# codeigniter secure opening of pdf file in new tab

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter, pdf, target

There are many similar questions to this but none quite answers my problem. I have users who wish to be able to access certain pdf files via a password. I have set up a page, accessed via a password, and the page contains links to each pdf. I have added an .htaccess file into the folder with the code 'deny from all' which successfully defeats any attempt to type in the url directly. (Unfortunately the pdfs are of a nautical magazine called 'The Log', in a folder called 'log' with endless scope for confusion over logging in. Sigh.) At present, when users click on a link for one of the pdfs, a direct link wouldn't work because of the protecting .htaccess file. So they are taken to a controller method as below:

```
   function loadlog($year='',$filename='')
  {
    $realpath = 'public/pdf/log/'.$year.'/'.$filename;
    $tofile= realpath('public/pdf/log/'.$year.'/'.$filename);
    header('Content-Type: application/pdf');
    readfile($tofile);
  }
```

This works fine except that the pdf opens in the same window. I would prefer not to do that as clicking the browser back button calls for more clicks to resend the page request. How can I get it to open in a new window ie the same effect as if I had been able to use a direct link with target=_blank?

Or have I tackled the entire problem the wrong way?

Comment: Add `target="_blank"` to whatever the link is that the user clicks to trigger this controller method …?

Comment: Thank you very much. I have been puzzling over this blindingly obvious problem for hours - too late at night probably. Someone needs to give me a serious talking to!!